# Sum of python dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I now want to ask for the account_id in l2 equal to the total amount of id in l1, but I have some problems with the for loop, I am a newbie, thanks for answering my questions

```
l1 = [{'id': 1, 'account': '12345678'}, {'id': 3, 'account': '12345678'}, {'id': 5, 'account': '12345678'},
      {'id': 147, 'account': '12345678'}, ]
l2 = [{'account_id': 1, 'amount': 123}, {'account_id': 1, 'amount': 145}, {'account_id': 1, 'amount': 10.2},
      {'account_id': 147, 'amount': 15}, {'account_id': 147, 'amount': 195}, {'account_id': 5, 'amount': 145}, ]

#for i in range(len(l2)):
#    for j in range(len(l1)):
#       l1[j]['amount_all'] = 0
#        if l2[i].get('account_id') == l1[j].get('id'):
#           l1[j]['amount_all'] += l2[i].get('amount')
for j in range(len(l1)):
    l1[j]['amount_all'] = 0
    for i in range(len(l2)):
            if l2[i].get('account_id') == l1[j].get('id'):
                l1[j]['amount_all'] += l2[i].get('amount')

print(l1)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!, please provide minimal working example.

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = [{'id': 1, 'account': '12345678'}, {'id': 3, 'account': '12345678'}, {'id': 5, 'account': '12345678'},
      {'id': 147, 'account': '12345678'}, ]
l2 = [{'account_id': 1, 'amount': 123}, {'account_id': 1, 'amount': 145}, {'account_id': 1, 'amount': 10.2},
      {'account_id': 147, 'amount': 15}, {'account_id': 147, 'amount': 195}, {'account_id': 5, 'amount': 145}, ]

for v in l1:
    v['amount_all'] = 0
for i in range(len(l2)):
    for j in range(len(l1)):
        if l2[i].get('account_id') == l1[j].get('id'):
            l1[j]['amount_all'] =  l1[j].get('amount_all') + l2[i].get('amount')
```

Sorry a little hard to parse what you wanted, this is what I guessed at, you were overriding the "amount_all" key in your dictionary because in your inner for loop you would see account_id 3 times in the account_id:1 example.

So if you just repopulate it with zero or check if it exists then it would work.

Comment: thanks,I swapped the positions of my two for loops solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = [{'id': 1, 'account': '12345678'}, {'id': 3, 'account': '12345678'}, {'id': 5, 'account': '12345678'},
      {'id': 147, 'account': '12345678'}, ]
l2 = [{'account_id': 1, 'amount': 123}, {'account_id': 1, 'amount': 145}, {'account_id': 1, 'amount': 10.2},
      {'account_id': 147, 'amount': 15}, {'account_id': 147, 'amount': 195}, {'account_id': 5, 'amount': 145}, ]

for i in range(len(l1)):
    l1[i]['amount_all'] = 0
    for j in range(len(l2)):
        if l2[j].get('account_id') == l1[i].get('id'):
            l1[i]['amount_all'] += l2[j].get('amount')
print(l1)
```

I just swapped the for loop position,it works fine as you need